# Apache Camel and Apache FTP Server on Windows - Can't find the "from" directory

Tags: apache-camel, apache-ftpserver

I am trying to set up an FTP client using Apache Camel with the FTP component. I'm currently using Apache FTP Server (https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/index.html) as the server implementation. I'm running the server with the provided standalone server. This is currently being done on a Windows 10 box, but will eventually be used in a Linux environment.

I run the server with the provided "typical" configuration, which allows anonymous login, on port 2121.

```
C:\Users\JO24447\Applications\apache-ftpserver-1.1.1\bin>ftpd.bat C:\Users\JO24447\Applications\apache-ftpserver-1.1.1\res\conf\ftpd-typical.xml
Using XML configuration file C:\Users\JO24447\Applications\apache-ftpserver-1.1.1\res\conf\ftpd-typical.xml...
FtpServer started
```

I have the FTP route set up as follows:

```
<route id="ftp-get">
  <from uri="ftp://{{ftp-client.server.host}}:{{ftp-client.server.port}}/{{ftp-client.source-dir}}?separator=Windows" />
  <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - ftp-get" />
  <to uri="file:{{ftp-client.dest-dir}}" />
  <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - ftp-get" />
</route>
```

**Note**: I've tried setting the `separator` to `Auto` and `Windows`, but had the same results.

I have properties set as follows (application.yml):

```
ftp-client:
  server:
    host: localhost
    port: 2121
  source-dir: C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel\ftp-client\src\main\resources\source
  dest-dir: dest
```

When I run the client, I get errors indicating that it can't find the path. The FTP server log shows similar errors:

console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

[...]
2020-04-23 08:51:40.098  INFO 10440 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: ftp-get started and consuming from: ftp://localhost:2121/C:%5CUsers%5CJO24447%5Cworkspace%5Cmission_services_camel%5Cmission-services-camel%5Cftp-client%5Csrc%5Cmain%5Cresources%5Csource
2020-04-23 08:51:40.102  INFO 10440 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2020-04-23 08:51:40.102  INFO 10440 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Apache Camel 3.1.0 (CamelContext: FTPClient) started in 0.286 seconds
2020-04-23 08:51:40.111  INFO 10440 --- [           main] e.m.l.m.ApplicationMain                  : Started ApplicationMain in 2.933 seconds (JVM running for 5.057)
2020-04-23 08:51:41.102  WARN 10440 --- [ources%5Csource] .r.RemoteFilePollingConsumerPollStrategy : Trying to recover by force disconnecting from remote server and re-connecting at next poll: ftp://anonymous@localhost:2121
2020-04-23 08:51:41.106  WARN 10440 --- [ources%5Csource] o.a.c.c.f.r.FtpConsumer                  : Consumer FtpConsumer[ftp://localhost:2121/C:%5CUsers%5CJO24447%5Cworkspace%5Cmission_services_camel%5Cmission-services-camel%5Cftp-client%5Csrc%5Cmain%5Cresources%5Csource?separator=Windows] failed polling endpoint: ftp://localhost:2121/C:%5CUsers%5CJO24447%5Cworkspace%5Cmission_services_camel%5Cmission-services-camel%5Cftp-client%5Csrc%5Cmain%5Cresources%5Csource?separator=Windows. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - File operation failed: 550 No such directory.
 Cannot change directory to: C:. Code: 550]

org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 550 No such directory.
 Cannot change directory to: C:. Code: 550
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.doChangeDirectory(FtpOperations.java:877) ~[camel-ftp-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(FtpOperations.java:855) ~[camel-ftp-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer.doPollDirectory(FtpConsumer.java:135) ~[camel-ftp-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer.pollDirectory(FtpConsumer.java:103) ~[camel-ftp-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:133) ~[camel-file-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187) [camel-support-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:106) [camel-support-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_241]
```

FTP server log:

```
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,062 [] [127.0.0.1] CREATED
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,063 [] [127.0.0.1] OPENED
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,064 [] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 220 Service ready for new user.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,065 [] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: USER anonymous
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,066 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 331 Guest login okay, send your complete e-mail address as password.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,067 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: PASS 
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,067 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] Anonymous login success - null
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,068 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 230 User logged in, proceed.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,068 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: TYPE A
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,068 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 200 Command TYPE okay.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,069 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: PWD
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,069 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 257 "/" is current directory.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,069 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: CWD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel\ftp-client\src\main\resources\source
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,070 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No such directory.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,070 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel\ftp-client\src\main\resources\source
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,071 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace/mission_services_camel/mission-services-camel/ftp-client/src/main/resources/source.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,071 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,072 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,072 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,073 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,073 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,073 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,074 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,074 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,074 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,075 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace/mission_services_camel.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,075 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,076 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace/mission_services_camel/mission-services-camel.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,076 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel\ftp-client
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,077 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace/mission_services_camel/mission-services-camel/ftp-client.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,077 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel\ftp-client\src
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,077 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace/mission_services_camel/mission-services-camel/ftp-client/src.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,078 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel\ftp-client\src\main
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,078 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace/mission_services_camel/mission-services-camel/ftp-client/src/main.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,078 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel\ftp-client\src\main\resources
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,079 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace/mission_services_camel/mission-services-camel/ftp-client/src/main/resources.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,079 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: MKD C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\mission_services_camel\mission-services-camel\ftp-client\src\main\resources\source
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,080 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No permission to create /C:/Users/JO24447/workspace/mission_services_camel/mission-services-camel/ftp-client/src/main/resources/source.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,080 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: CWD /
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:38,081 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 250 Directory changed to /

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,082 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: NOOP
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,083 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 200 Command NOOP okay.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,083 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: PWD
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,084 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 257 "/" is current directory.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,084 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: CWD C:
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,085 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 550 No such directory.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,086 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] RECEIVED: QUIT
[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,087 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] SENT: 221 Goodbye.

[ INFO] 2020-04-23 08:53:39,087 [anonymous] [127.0.0.1] CLOSED
```

There are a number of components involved, many of which are new to me. A couple of questions that come up are:

- Does the Apache FTP server work on Windows (or with Windows style paths)? It says it should, but sometimes that's not always true. I know that Windows style paths often cause problems.
- The Camel FTP component is a little vague on the path(s). It says that you shouldn't use an absolute path. How is it going to find the path(s) you're using? This is confusing.
- Is my camel route set up correctly?
- Am I specifying the paths correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use windows style paths with drive letters - its not a FTP standard. So remove the c: prefix off the path. And also mind the path is relative to the home directory of the user logging into the FTP server. So typically you wont have a path or you have a small path like /inbox or /acme/download (where acme is a client name etc).

Comment: Just re-read your comment. How do I have a path relative to the home directory of user anonymous?

Comment: OK, after a little thinking and experimentation, I found that the anonymous user set up in the FTP server's config, has its home directory located at: C:\Users\JO24447\Applications\apache-ftpserver-1.1.1\res\home. There was an existing README file in that directory. When I ran my client, it was successfully transferred into my destination directory. For this to work on the client end, I changed the ftp route "source dir" to the "current" directory (i.e. ".").

Comment: Now the question becomes: can I change the home directory to some other arbitrary location? I'm assuming that's more of a question for the FTP server.

Comment: Yes the home directory is something that is configured on the FTP server. You can use relative starting in Camel, and its by default (in latest releases) jailed to be within the home directory or its sub folder. To go outside you need to turn off jail, and then you can use ../../ to go up in parent folders. But generally its bad design, instead stay in the home folder if possible.